# How Write every 7 image inside row by smarty?

Tags: php, html-table, smarty

I want to draw every 7 images inside row, how make it by Smarty?

```
<table width="838" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">                            
    {section name=index loop=$ArrGallery}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{$ArrGallery[index].gallery_path}" width="150" height="100" style=" position:relative; z-index:1; padding:7px;"/>
            <a href="" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; padding-top:50px; margin-right:20px;">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {/section}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a table with a fixed number of cells per row, use css's float property. The objects you float will stack themselves onto the left side of their container until they fill it, then fill the next row, and so on. By adjusting the width of the container, you control the number of items per row. For example:

```
<div style="width:560px;">
  {section name=index loop=$ArrGallery}
    <img src="{$ArrGallery[index].gallery_path}" style="float:left;width:150px;height:100px;padding:7px;"/>
  {/section}
</div>
```

Adjust the div's width until 7 images fill each row (except perhaps the last row).

Comment: Whilst I would usually recommend this, if the images are a form of tabular data in nature, then a `<table>` is the correct solution.  Relying on width is a bit risky, what if it changes?

Comment: @Mahran I've adjusted my answer to use your template.

Comment: thanks i fix it by using mod function in thw end of td          {if ($ArrGallery[index].serial mod 4) eq 0}
</tr>
{/if}
{/section}